# Replacing variable text in between two known elements

Tags: python, text, replace

```
s = """Comment=This is a comment
Name=Frank J. Lapidus
GenericName=Some name"""
replace_name = "Dr. Jack Shephard"
```

I have some text in a file and have been trying to figure out how to search and replace a line so Name=Frank J. Lapidus becomes Name=Dr. Jack Shephard

How could I do this in Python? Edited: (BTW, the second element would be a \n just in case you were wondering).

Thanks.

Comment: what this has to do with "known element"? you seem to know what exactly you want to replace!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace the text between "Name=" and the end of the line? Is the whole file in the "Something=" format? Are you doing more replacements than this single one?

Comment: Have you come across `ConfigParser`? Would it be useful to you? http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Comment: Hi Lennart. Sorry sorry for the confusion. Yes, just like you said. The value of the Something= is variable, so like you said whatever is in between Something= and \n 
It won't happen for every single value but for some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the regular expression functions from the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module. For example like this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^Name=(.*)$", flags=re.MULTILINE)
re.sub(pattern, "Name=%s" % replace_name, s)
```

(The `re.MULTILINE` option makes `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of a line, respectively, in addition to the beginning and the end of the string.)

---

**Edited to add:** Based on your comments to [Emil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388365/replacing-variable-text-in-between-two-known-elements/4388401#4388401), it seems you are manipulating [Desktop Entry](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) files. Their syntax seems to be quite close to that used by the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module (perhaps some differences in the case-sensitivity of section names, and the expectation that comments should be preserved across a parse/serialize cycle).

An example:

```
import ConfigParser
parser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
parser.optionxform = str # make option names case sensitive
parser.read("/etc/skel/examples.desktop")
parser.set("Desktop Entry", "Name", replace_name)
parser.write(open("modified.desktop", "w"))
```

Comment: Kiitos Jukka. Both examples work great. I noticed ConfigParser seems to remove all comments including the #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open line (Yikes!), but I'm just studying the module's docs now to see if I can figure what to do about it. 
ConfigParser looks very handy. I'm sure I'm going to have a lot of fun with this. 
Hyvää Joulua!

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.replace` (documented under http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```
>>> s = """Comment=This is a comment
... Name=Frank J. Lapidus
... GenericName=Some name"""
>>> replace_name = "Dr. Jack Shephard"
>>> s.replace("Frank J. Lapidus", replace_name)
'Comment=This is a comment\nName=Dr. Jack Shephard\nGenericName=Some name'
```

Comment: I would replace `Name=Frank J. Lapidus` by `Name=<replace_name>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the value of Name= is totally variable. I've been working on... 
s = """Comment=This is an info icon
Name=Click to receive weather info
GenericName=info icon"""
find_name = re.search('Name=', s)
f = open('test.desktop','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    if find_name:
        line = line.replace(line, ("Name=" + "Hello" + "\n"))
    print line

f.close()
but it's not turning out how I expected. I'll keep messing with this though.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the regular expression solution (Jukka's), if you're looking to do many of these replacements and the entire file is structured in this way, convert the entire file into a dictionary and then write it back out again after some replacements:

```
d = dict(x.split("=") for x in s.splitlines() if x.count("=") is 1)
d["Name"] = replace_name
new_string = "\n".join(x+"="+y for x,y in d.iteritems())
```

Caveats: 
First, this only works if there are no '=' signs in your field names (it ignores lines that don't have exactly one = sign). 
Second, converting to dict and back will not preserve the order of the fields, although you can at least sort the dictionary with some additional work.